How to implement <post-right restoration> in pine script
I referred to the pine V5 document and found the following code method to obtain the closing price of "NVIDIA" stock's , but the displayed price is not what I need.
extendedTicker = ticker.modify("NASDAQ:NVDA", adjustment.none)
aaplExtAdj = request.security(extendedTicker, timeframe.period, close)
plot(aaplExtAdj)

The price after the right restoration should be 1412.90, but it shows the current closing price of 141.25. How should I modify the code?

//@version=5
study("NVDA Closing Price")

// Getting the closing price
nvda_close = close

// Plotting the closing price
plot(nvda_close, title="NVDA Close", color=color.blue, linewidth=2) or //@version=5
study("NVDA Closing Price")

// Getting closing price for different timeframe
nvda_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", close) // For 4-hour closing price

plot(nvda_close, title="NVDA Close", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)

